# How to prevent infinite loop in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, infinite-loop

Hi I am new to react and unfortunately I get an infinite loop with this code, and am not sure why. This is the code in question:

```
if (projectInfo) {
        console.log('Length is', projectInfo.length);

        for (let i = 0; i < projectInfo.length; i++) {
            setValues({ ...values, fromDates: projectInfo[i].fromDate });
            console.log('i is', i);
        }
    }
```

The whole component is here:

```
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Map from '../../shared/components/Map/Map';

export default function FieldworkInofrmation(props) {
    const projectInfo = props.props.fieldwork;

    const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
        fromDates: ' ',
    });

    if (projectInfo) {
        console.log('Length is', projectInfo.length);

        for (let i = 0; i < projectInfo.length; i++) {
            setValues({ ...values, fromDates: projectInfo[i].fromDate });
            console.log('i is', i);
        }
    }

    return (
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Box fontWeight="fontWeightBold" m={1}>
                    Fieldwork Information
                </Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Box fontWeight="fontWeightLight" m={1}>
                    Click on map point to view details for the point
                </Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Map />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Box fontWeight="fontWeightLight" m={1}>
                    Type:
                </Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Box fontWeight="fontWeightLight" m={1}>
                    Period:
                </Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Box fontWeight="fontWeightLight" m={1}>
                    From:
                </Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Box fontWeight="fontWeightLight" m={1}>
                    To:
                </Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Box fontWeight="fontWeightLight" m={1}>
                    Coordinates:
                </Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Box fontWeight="fontWeightLight" m={1}>
                    Station:
                </Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={1}>
                <Box fontWeight="fontWeightLight" m={1}>
                    Location:
                </Box>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

I tried inserting "i++" at the end of the for-looop but still got the error: "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop". What could I do to solve this?

Comment: I think you could use `useEffect`

Comment: When you call `setValues()`, React is going to update the component's state. Which means your `FieldworkInofrmation` function runs again, in full. Which calls `setValues()`. Etc etc, -> infinite loop. Put the state update in a function, then pass the function to `useEffect()`. Also, looking at your code, why are you even setting the state? You're not using it anywhere else, and it doesn't change inside your component. And from the looks of it you're merely copying props to state?

Comment: `fromDates` is a property on your `values` state object. By (what should be) the end of the loop, it will just have the value of the last element in the `projectInfo` prop. Basically `projectInfo[projectInfo.length - 1].fromDate`. Im guess this isn't what you want... Is `values.fromDates` suppose to be an array? or maybe an object with different keys? If you let us know what  you are trying to achieve (and what `fromDates` is meant to be) it will be easier to answer the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the reason you're getting an infinite loop is because you're updating the state during rendering, which causes a re-render, which updates the state again, and so on.

Since all you're trying to do is effectively set the initial state, there is no need to use the "setState" method (or in your case "setValues").

Simply do the following:

```
const projectInfo = props.props.fieldwork;

const initialValues = {
    fromDates: ' ',
};

if (projectInfo) {
    for (let i = 0; i < projectInfo.length; i++) {
        initialValues = { ...initialValues, fromDates: projectInfo[i].fromDate };
    }
}

const [values, setValues] = React.useState(initialValues);
```

However, in your current implementation you're constantly overriding the value of "fromDates". I suspect that `values` should be an array of objects, each with its own "fromDates" field. For instance:

```
const projectInfo = props.props.fieldwork;

const initialValues = [{
    fromDates: ' ',
}] // this is now an array

if (projectInfo) {
    for (let i = 0; i < projectInfo.length; i++) {
        initialValues.push({ fromDates: projectInfo[i].fromDate });
    }
}

const [values, setValues] = React.useState(initialValues); // `values` will now have an array of objects [{ fromDate: ' ' }, { fromDate: 'Oct 14th, 2019' }, ...]
```

Lastly, if your intention is indeed to override "fromDate" and all you care about is the latest value, there is no need for a loop at all. Simply set the latest value in the `projectInfo` array:

```
const projectInfo = props.props.fieldwork;

const initialValues = {
    fromDates: ' ',
};

if (projectInfo) {
    initialValues.fromDates = projectInfo[projectInfo.length -1].fromDates;
}

const [values, setValues] = React.useState(initialValues);
```

The last solution was also mentioned by @Ghojzilla in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is bad, state gets updated every time

```
if (projectInfo) {
    console.log('Length is', projectInfo.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < projectInfo.length; i++) {
        setValues({ ...values, fromDates: projectInfo[i].fromDate });
        console.log('i is', i);
    }
}
```

This is good, state updated once

```
if (projectInfo) {
    console.log('Length is', projectInfo.length);
    let newValues = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < projectInfo.length; i++) {
        newValues = {
           ...newValues,
           ...values,
           fromDates: projectInfo[i].fromDate
        };
        console.log('i is', i);
    }
    setValues(newValues);
}
```

still not sure why would you override `fromDates` each time

Comment: Thank you! This is better, but I still get the same error. The reason why I am doing this is that I get an unknown number of objects from the API. It could be 1, 2, 3... etc. So I am trying to update the values without knowing how many times it needs to be updated in advance